# Lebesgue integral vs Riemann integral in terms of completeness of the space of integrable functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, soft-question, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

When asked what are the advantages of the Lebesgue integral over the Riemann integral, a common answer is that the space of Riemann integrable functions is not complete, whereas the space of Lebesgue integrable functions is complete.

However, I think the space of Riemann integrable functions on a closed interval is complete with respect to the uniform norm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_integrability

What is the advantage of the Lebesgue integral over the Riemann integral in terms of completeness of the space of integrable functions?

Comment: The common answer refers to the metric $d(f,g)=\int |f-g|$, not to the uniform metric. You get completeness w.r.t. this metric if you use Lebesgue integral but not if you use Riemann integral.

Comment: @geetha290krm Why is the completeness w.r.t. that metric more important than the completeness w.r.t.  the uniform metric?

Comment: Uniform metric is not even directly related to integration. So your completeness assertion looks artificial.